# Ubuntu network interface randomly across reboots doesn't take the needed IP address

Tags: ubuntu, networking, interface

On Ubuntu Server 22.04.2 I'm using netplan which is set up with systemd-networkd as follows:

```
network:
version: 2
renderer: networkd
ethernets:
eth0:
addresses:
- 1.1.1.1/24
gateway4: 1.1.1.1
nameservers:
addresses:
- 1.1.1.1
search:
- hidden
eth1: {}
eth2: {}
eth3: {}
bonds:
bond0:
interfaces: [eth1, eth2, eth3]
parameters:
mode: balance-rr
mii-monitor-interval: 100
```

Please do not mind the indentation or the ip addresses (it's not a syntax issue or anything) . The problem is that seemingly randomly when rebooting the system my eth0 doesn't take the IP address that it is **supposed ** to meaning I lose SSH access to the server. I have NetworkManager fully disabled and masked, I only have systemd-networkd running. I can reboot 10 times and the 11th time the interface won't set up properly as an example. What exactly is causing any of this?

I have tried a lot of things starting with setting the matching mac address of the interface in the netplan configuration, setting udev rules, using NetworkManager instead